# Can surrogate bodies compete with normal human bodies?

Tags: sports, body-modification

Context:

- In the near future surrogate bodies become common, this helps people to get to work, travel, and so on, without actually leaving their home.
- People still, however, get out of their house using their own body, especially when they need not move far from their homes.
- As per government policy, the second body is actually a man-made clone of the user, meaning that the second body still needs food, water, and other things a normal human body needs.
- The people feel what their second body feel; both metaphorically and literally.
- the user has full complete control on the second body. as for second body can't be controlled or "alive" without it's user. and it went brain dead until the user comeback.
- when the second body was used, the first one didn't do anything as the user controlled the second body.
- and for note, yes this is a reference to the movie surrogates(2009). the idea is also  the same here.except their body is now made of bodily tissue.

My question:

As many people start to go to work with their second body, would it be allowed for athletes to compete with people who use their second body?

Comment: This is already a matter of opinion in our real world, see the examples of allowed/forbidden medicines and "tools". How is that going to be any different in your world?

Comment: Sure but they have to compete under a different category.

Comment: Do humans somehow inhabit these surrogates, or are they more like proxies? Allowed by what or whom? If these surrogates are clones, do they have different rights? How can they be told apart from regular human beings?

Comment: @Joachim the OP is clearly talking about surrogates as per [the film of the same name](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogates&ved=2ahUKEwj2lZOHvdT2AhVjoFwKHbKgCE0QFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1HJkxjoNLJJDdNvvLm6eyS) with just the one difference being that they're organic rather than mechanical, so no brain of their own, no brain no rights.

Comment: @Pelinore "Clearly"? I beg to differ - nowhere is that reference made. I'm not familiar with that film, and I don't think I ought to be to interpret the question properly, and what made you think your interpretation was the right one (before it was confirmed by the OP)? Besides, 'surrogate' is a broad term.

Comment: @Joachim im sorry, but what pelinore said was right.

Comment: No need for apologies, it simply was not clear, and that fact alone does not answer my questions - and it shouldn't. A question should be self-containing, so please add any relevant details to your question.

Comment: As edited, I don't see this as opinion based: it's a *yes or no* question.  As a matter of worldbuilding, I really don't understand the downvotes! This is an excellent question of science, technology & ethics that not only has historical precedent but is also a question the real world may soon have to wrestle with. This particular situation is exactly what Sci-Fi does best: address real moral and ethical questions in the context of the almost real yet fantastically advanced setting! Vote to Leave Open, and Upvote!

Comment: Thank you for the update, faddllz :)

Answer (score 1):

**Body similarities**

If second body is 100% clone of the first body and they have same

- muscular strength
- feeling of pain
- mental level
- tactics and techniques
- physical dimensions

then an athlete can send his second body in the competition. But if any of the above things is different and it gives him advantage (or disadvantage) over the other athletes, then it is prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"would it be allowed for athletes to compete with people who **use** second body ?"*

**Like horse sports**

You say "use". This question seems to imply that people delegate their clone to the olympics, to compete with other humans. The clone owner will receive the honours, if their clone wins. It would be a separate category, like horse riding. I'd say let clones only compete against clones.

**As the question is put, it would *not* be fair play**

Your clone will have all the time of the world, to exercise muscles and improve for certain sports. Your cloned body puts all the effort, it will take all the risks, e.g. risk of sports injury. If the owner of the clone would get the medal, it would not be honest competition with other sporters, who devote their lives and train their own body, to accomplish something in sports.

**Your clones are body extensions**

I think your clones have no relevant status as a person now: they are only active when their "boss" chooses that. They will execute exactly what their "boss" wants their body to do. It is like using a body extension, which (on Earth) is not allowed in sports.

Whether the accomplishments of clones will be recognized, will depend on the clone's status. How it develops. Will clones eventually become independent, will they be recognized as an individual and entitled to receive the medal themselves ? But that would become a different question.

Comment: what i mean second body is that is akin to what it depicted in movie surrogates. the human have complete control over the second body and if they aren't in the second body , it went brain dead.

Comment: @faddiz I understand, but that won't really change the answer. When a jockey dies, the horse will have trouble adjusting to that new situation. It won't get brain-dead, but it will actually *mourn* the jockey and it can even loose the ability to compete on top level. You would allow VR players of the FIFA game to compete as solid holograms in a real competition?

Answer (score 1):

A clone can be interpreted in different ways:

- An exact clone would have the same body proportions and capabilities as the owner. There is almost no advantage in this. When you use the clone to move around, you are spreading the amount of movement both bodies get and reduce their physical fitness. Unless the job your clone is doing is dangerous/bad for your health this is not a good option. At best you might try to increase the time you have per day. If your real body has been inactive all day it has more energy to do stuff in the evening. You could also reduce things like commuting time by storing the clone at work or similar, and during breaks you eat and train your real body and use electro stimulation when you are controlling.

You could perhaps introduce multiple control methods, one of which being a VR experience where you can move your real body simultaneously with the surrogate body, so your body remains active.

- an improved clone would have been manipulated for superior physical capabilities. if the body is "normal" after that, the clone is mostly useful for one game of sports. Afterwards you would need to manually keep the body in tiptop shape. While using the clone would give an advantage in starting fitness it would then depend on the user to keep it that way, meaning it's fitness will equalize at the point where the athlete would have been anyway. Ofcourse you are again spreading activity of the main body and surrogate body, which will impact the physical fitness and lifespan of the user. Outside of athletes the improved body surrogates would function to let handicapped people move and live as others do.

If the clone keeps its physical fitness without much input from the user then sports would simply create a different category of clone-sports. Just like we have different weight classes in boxing for example.

In either case some sports might even move to be exclusively clone-sports. It reduces the risks of permanent injuries and many top sports are so demanding of the body that it severely impacts their later life. It could also herald an era of less restrictions and more violent sports. If the head injury is going to affect the clone but not the owner then many rules and regulations can be done away with. Why add safety like a seatbelt or rollcage to a racecar if instant death is preferable than having the owner suffer through the clone? Why not dope up some surrogates so they barely feel pain, then have them fight in any way they like? From simple bare-knuckle boxing to deathmatches.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no check against genetically editing ("refining") the surrogate/clone body, then I'd say a whole different sporting event with the same disciplines would be required, similar to Youth Olympics and Paraolympics.

In this case there should probably be clone-olympics that might just serve as a rather exclusive event where the rich show off what the clone bodies can do that they've had expensively cultivated. Of course, within regulations and  with pre-event genetic screening and maybe even more regular drug tests.